# Android different paths returned for the same file

Tags: android, file, path

In my code, you can either import or export csv files. The export function works well, for the creation of the file, I use this for the path:

Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)

It returns the following path:
/storage/emulated/0/Download/File.CSV

In my Import function, I use a createchooser which gets a file explorer to find the file to import. If I select the same file and ask for the path with the following code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_FILE_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uriFile = data.getData();
                Log.v("testimport", uriFile.getPath());
                File fileToImport = new File(uriFile.getPath());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToImport));
```

I get a file not found error with the following path:
/document/primary:Download/StudyMemory/File.csv

Why do I get two differents paths? How can I get the absolute path of the uri coming from the file explorer?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'LISTANGFR.csv'. That looks a different file to begin with.

Comment: 'which gets a browser to find the file to import'. Don't think so. Maybe a file explorer?

Comment: I edited the post to correct the typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 'path is a file system path. The second one a content provider path.

As you want to read the file you better open an input stream like

```
 InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputSteam(uriFile);
```

And use the stream for your readers.

Comment: Thanks! The answer works and answers perfectly to my question.